# PROBLEM: Everything back to zero

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I am new to Blender, and i am practicing by modeling all sorts of things. But every time, when i am nearly finished, my whole scene, everything from mesh to materials, is back to the default start (the same as when you just opened a new project).

I have no idea how this happens, but if any of you knows what this is, please tell me. It happens every time.

Comment: Hi JustDaniël. There is no way to know what steps you take from the description of the problem, so it is difficult to answer what it is or to reproduce the issue. Maybe try watching a few video tutorials about using Blender and try to learn how to use it effectively in the first place. You will find many tutorials on YouTube. If you still struggle, please explain your problem in more detail so it could be reproduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you pressed Ctrl+N (New) ?

If you saved your project, just reopen the last save. You'll lose the work done since the last save, but it's better than nothing.

If you didn't saved (very bad habit), Blender auto-save every 2 minutes (you can change the delay in **User Preferences / Files**). The files are kept in the temp directory ("/tmp" on Linux or Mac, "C:\tmp" on Windows).